# My app dont's show the Compatibility with iPhone6 and iPhone6+ in Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created an application in Xcode5 with two xib for iPhone4 and iPhone5 and I am not using auto layout.now my app is perfectly running in both devices iphone6 and iphone6+ without any ui problem.I also upgrade my Xcode5 to Xcode6.1. my code is also supported 64bit architecture.

I added all icons and splash images with the following size and name.

```
 1. Icon.png          57x57                 
 2. Icon@2x.png     114x114 
 3. Icon-72.png       72x72
 4. Icon-72@2x.png  144x144
 5. Icon-76.png       76x76
 6. Icon-76@2x.png  152x152
 7. Icon-120.png    120x120
 8. Icon-60@3x.png  180x180
```

Default images:

```
 1. Default-568h.png              320x568
 2. Default-568h@2x.png          640x1136
 3. Default-667h@2x.png          750x1334
 4. Default-Portrait-736h.png   1242x2208
 5. Default-Portrait.png         768x1004
 6. Default-Portrait@2x.png     1536x2008
 7. Default-Retina.png           768x1024
 8. Default-Retina@2x.png       1536x2048
 9. Default.png                   320x480
 10. Default@2x.png               640x960
```

Now i uploaded my app in appstore and it successfully approved but it didn't show me the compatible with iPhone6 and iPhone6+.So please guide me if i forgotten to add something or not follow the proper step to make it compatible with iPhone6 and iPhone6+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Launchscreen.xib to let the App store know your App is compatible with iPhone 6 and 6 plus. iPhone 6 and 6 plus have different size for screen so you need to create two more xib to fit the needed like you had created two xib for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.